# Ajax and Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to find out why I keep getting a 500 server error on this. I have it set up correctly in my routes as I've provided and all I'm doing is returning the string haha just to see if it hits the route.

```
Route::post('roster/getRosterMembers', ['as' => 'roster.getRosterMembers', 'uses' => 'RosterMembersController@getRosterMembers']);

(function(document, window, $) {
    $('#type_id').change(function() {
        var type = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/roster/getRosterMembers",
            token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        })
        .success(function( data ) {
            if ( console && console.log ) {
                    console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
            }
        })
        .error(function() {
            alert('Hello');
        });
    });


})(document, window, jQuery);

public function getRosterMembers() {
    return 'haha';
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included 500 error

Comment: A 500 error is generated by your `php` code and not the `ajax` check your code in the controller or model. Additionally if the route do not exist or your controller also do not exist you will get also an error

Comment: I don't understand though because all I'm doing at the moment is returning a string.

Comment: Do you have this controller and provided method or you are also faking the controller.

Comment: The getRosterMembers method is in a controller.

Comment: That is not the proper way to set the `CSRF` token

Comment: and what network log says?

Comment: Place this in your blade file **before** any of your other javascript: `$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });`

Comment: is alert('hello'); being triggered?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'` it's `_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'`. Note the `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can insert these codes in your view files:

Insert these between

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Insert this script:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

This will automatically insert CSRF token in the headers of all of your AJAX calls

From: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token